# java math.sqrt from array element

Tags: java, arrays

I've got two problems. Please find my code attached below:

```
public class Numbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] tab = { 9.0, 27, 5, 77 };
        System.out.println("array size: " + tab.length);

        for (int y = 0; y < tab.length; y++) {
            System.out.printf("%d", (int) tab[y]);
            System.out.print("    ");
            System.out.print(Math.sqrt(y));
            System.out.println();
        }

        // for(double i:tab){
        // System.out.println(tab[(int) i]);
        // }

    }
}
```

And now

1) my first problem is that I have some numbers in my array `tab` and then in the FOR loop I want to display in each line the element and its square root.
But for the first element i get 0.0 as a square root. why?  The other results are wrong as well to me.

my outcome:

```
array size: 4
9    0.0
27    1.0
5    1.4142135623730951
77    1.7320508075688772
```

2) second problem is with my for each loop which is commented. But when you uncomment it the it doesnt work because I get an error. 
The output:

```
array size: 4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
```

What did I do wrong with this for each loop?
Why eclipse shows that I ask about 9-th element?

Thank you for help in advance - all answers are appreciated :)

Comment: Please ask a single question per post. (You've now actually got two answers, one to each problem. But these should be in different posts...)

Comment: ok, sorry - I will do this next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you try to retrieve data from array in the index out of bounds,
ty to change this:

```
    for(double i : tab){ 
       System.out.println(tab[(int) i]);
      }
```

With this:

```
  for(double i : tab){
    System.out.println(i);
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

> But for the first element i get 0.0 as a square root. why?

Because you are getting the square root of the loop index, not the value stored at the index!

```
System.out.print(Math.sqrt(y));
```

Should be changed to

```
System.out.print(Math.sqrt(tab[y]));
```

> second problem is with my for each loop which is commented. But when you uncomment it the it doesnt work because I get an error.

You are just misinterpreting the purpose of the "enhanced for loop":

```
 for(double i:tab){
     // System.out.println(tab[(int) i]);  // Wrong! 
     System.out.println(i);
 }
```

That's what you want. This loop says: "Give me every element of `tab`, one at a time, and store it in `i` for this loop". Even though you've named your variable `i`, it is not a loop index, it's the actual value held in the array.

Comment: thanx a lot - that explain everything :)

Answer (score 2):

> But for the first element i get 0.0 as a square root. why?

Because you're not printing out the square root of the element - you're printing out the square root of the index. This:

```
System.out.print(Math.sqrt(y));
```

should be:

```
System.out.print(Math.sqrt(tab[y]));
```

Answer (score 2):

First Problem:
You are not using the elements from the array, but your loop parameter:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] tab = { 9.0, 27, 5, 77 };
        System.out.println("array size: " + tab.length);

        for (int y = 0; y < tab.length; y++) {
            System.out.printf("%d", (int) tab[y]);
            System.out.print("    ");
            System.out.print(Math.sqrt(tab[y]));
            System.out.println();
        }
}
```

(this would be the correct code)

Second Problem:
You are using an foreach loop, so there is no need to use an index to get an array element:

```
for(double i : tab){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```